# What is the recommended way to access instance variables and methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
ViewController.h

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *products;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewProducts;
```

i would like to know apple or developer recommended method of accessing instance variables and accessor methods.

Should i use _instanceVariable or self.instanceVariable or should i synthesize all ivars ?

Method 1

```
ViewController.m

@synthesize products;
@synthesize tableViewProducts;
@synthesize productCount;
......
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableViewProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellReuseIdentifier"];
productCount.
```

Method 2

```
ViewController.m

UITableViewCell *cell=[_tableViewProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellReuseIdentifier"];
```

Method 3

```
ViewController.m

UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableViewProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellReuseIdentifier"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always access properties with the accessor methods, so always use `self.property` etc. Except, in `init` (and `initWithWhatever` etc) methods, in which you should always access the backing variable directly `_property` etc. This is to avoid side effects of accessing `self` before `self` has finished initializing.

The reason you always want to use `self.property` is because that enables useful side effects. The accessor methods can be overridden to validate values, trigger KVO effects (automatically update views for example), use default values if no specific value has been set and much more. Those are bypassed if you use the backing variables directly.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't needed to use `@synthesize` for years now so don't bother adding those lines.

Since you have properties, access the properties, not the underlying instance variables.

This means your 3rd option is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you don't need to `@synthesize` properties. Since you've already defined your properties you even don't need to user the instance variable, simple use the property itself as `self.instanceVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to `@synthesize` all properties. But Can `@synthesize` property to create custom Setter Method.

`self.propertyName` will trigger this setter Method & `_propertyName` won't trigger.

**Example:**

**.h**

```
@property(string, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize name = _name;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = name;
}
```